# Basic modular arithmetic

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I know basic math, but do not have a clue about this. This is simple for you guys. Please guide me on how to sort this

What is $5\cdot 3 -4\cdot 2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_6$ ? (Hint recall the elements of $\mathbb{Z}_6$ are $\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ )

Find the dot product[1,3,2]..[4,5,1] in $\mathbb{Z}_5$

$\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ equation $x^2=3x$

Comment: What is $15\mod 6$ and $8\mod 6$?

Comment: so Z mean mod? i am learning this

Comment: No. Z should be supposed to mean the set of all integers $\mathbb{Z}$. When you write $\mathbb{Z}_6$ it means $\mod 6$.

Comment: so the answer should be 1 for the 1st question? if it yes how can solve the next two

Comment: what has been tried ?

Comment: @PEO: You are right! $15-8\equiv 1\mod 6$, since $15-8=7=1\mod 6$

Comment: thanks corman can you guide me how to sort the rest i am not expecting answers but want to know how to slove this

Comment: @PEO: I can help you with the equation. I do not know how the dot-product is defined. Maybe you can give the definition. I can help you with the equation. Since $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ you could solve it simply by trying every possible element $0,1,2,\dotso, 9$. Or try to solve $x^2-3x=0\mod 10$ which might remind you of a "normal" equation in $\mathbb{R}$. How do you procceed from there?

Comment: i think i got the answer for the last one x= 0, x= 3, x= 5, x=8 am i right @Cornman

Comment: @PEO: This is correct.

Comment: @PEO: I am not sure, but the "dot-product" should be calculated like this: $[a,b,c]\cdot [x,y,z]=ax+by+cy$. What is the solution, when you go after this?

Comment: ((9x2) + 6)(3+8+4)(1+(6x7)) Z10 this should be 0 isn't it and how can i sort the dot notation any term for that kind of series then i can find it out.

Comment: @PEO: $(9\cdot 2+6)(3+8+4)(1+6\cdot 7)=0\mod 10$, that is correct. I gave a formula for the dot-product in my last comment. Have you tried this? I am not sure if it is the correct definition. Look it up please.

Comment: yeap i THINK I GOT yapee yapee doo yes you are right @Cornman. it should be 1 now i know the basic i think. really appreciate your help. can you post sum up as answer so then i can mark it as answer

Comment: I posted an answer. Happy to help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)

$5\cdot 3-4\cdot 2=15-8=7=1\mod 6$

2)

$[1,3,2]\cdot [4,5,1]=1\cdot 4+3\cdot 5+2\cdot 1=4+15+2=21=1\mod 5$

3)

$x^2=3x\mod 10\Leftrightarrow x^2-3x=0\mod 10\Leftrightarrow x(x-3)=0\mod 10$

We see two solutions immediatly. $x=0$ and $x=3$. 
There can be more, since $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ contains zerodivisors.
We have to check if $x(x-3)=10n$ for some $x$.
With $x=5$, we get $5\cdot 2=10=0\mod 10$, and with $x=8$, we get $8\cdot 5=40=0\mod 10$.

There are no more solutions.

Comment: Thanks @Cornman

Comment: @PEO: Happy when I could help you. :)

Comment: definitely do when i get enough reputation. again thanks